# Jackson : Conditional select the fields

Tags: jackson

```
I have a scenario where i need to use the payload as 

{"authType":"PDS"}
or
{"authType":"xyz","authType2":"abc",}
or
{"authType":"xyz","authType2":"abc","authType3":"123"}
or
any combination except for null values.
```

referring to the code i have 3 fields but only not null value fields be used. 
    Basically i don't want to include the field which has null value.

Are there any annotations to be used to get it done

```
public  class AuthJSONRequest {

    private String authType;
    private String authType2;
    private String authType3;

    public String getAuthType() {
        return authType;
    }

    public void setAuthType(String authType) {
        this.authType = authType;
    }

    public String getAuthType2() {
        return authType2;
    }

    public void setAuthType2(String authType2) {
        this.authType2 = authType2;
    }
        public String getAuthType3() {
        return authType3;
    }

    public void setAuthType3(String authType3) {
        this.authType3 = authType3;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 10):

Try JSON Views? See [this](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews) or [this](http://www.jroller.com/RickHigh/entry/working_with_jackson_json_views). Or for more filtering features, see [this blog entry](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/02/entry_443.html) (Json Filters for example).

Answer (score 5):

This is exactly what the annotation [`@JsonInclude`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude) in Jackson2 and [`@JsonSerialize`](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.2.1/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/annotate/JsonSerialize.Inclusion.html) in Jackson are meant for.

If you want a property to show up only when it is not equal to `null`, add `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)` resp. `@JsonSerialize(include=Include.NON_NULL)`.